# c++ createprocess - string var for cmd line parameter - nothing happening

Tags: c++, string, std, createprocess

So I'm trying to create a process using string variables.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

si.cb = sizeof(si);

std::string cmd_line = game_path + " " + std::string(game_params);

std::cout << cmd_line << "\n";

if (!CreateProcess(NULL, LPTSTR(cmd_line.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    std::cout << "fail\n";
    return false;
}
```

The output from cout cmd_line is the correct path and parameters:

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My_Game\\Game.exe -test -admin
```

The createprocess call is returning false, but I'm not sure exactly why. I'm pretty new to this so any help and advice would be great.

Comment: [Right from the horse's mouth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx): "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError." I recommend starting by following the advice and getting some of that extended information. Might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm using the code here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm getting the error code 2 - file doesn't exist. I'm copying the path directly from the address bar, etc. It is for certain the right path unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    std::string game_path = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe";
    std::string game_params = "-test -admin";

    std::string cmd_line = game_path + " " + std::string(game_params);

    std::cout<<cmd_line << "\n";

    TCHAR tszCmdLine[1024] = {0};
    mbstowcs(tszCmdLine, cmd_line.c_str(), 1024);
    _tprintf(tszCmdLine);

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, tszCmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
        std::cout<<"fail\n"<<GetLastError();
        return false;
    }
}
```

`const char*` cannot be parameter of `CreateProcess()`. You have to make `char*` string to `tchar*` string using `mbstowcs()`

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed `LPTSTR(cmd_line.c_str())` was doing the needed conversions, lessons learned.

Comment: Since the code is converting to Unicode, `tszCmdLine` should be declared as `WCHAR[]` instead of `TCHAR[]`, and `CreateProcess` should be changed to `CreateProcessW` to match. And I would use a `std::vector` instead of a fixed array. Or better, change `cmd_line` to `std::wstring` and pass it to `CreateProcessW` using `&cmd_line[0]` instead of `cmd_line.c_str()`.

Comment: I think using `MultiByteToWideChar()` is better then `mbstowcs()`

Answer (score 2):

I've test your code.

The result of `GetLastError()` is 2.

That is `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Use `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert `char*` string to `TCHAR*` string.

```
MultiByteToWideChar(LC_ALL, 0, cmd_line.c_str(), -1, str_command, MAX_PATH);
```